# Can't get virtualbox VM to start on different host machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I recently downloaded a VPS server image and got it working on my mac under virtualbox. However, I've now copied the ova export to my linux server and I can't seem to get it to boot on that - I keep getting the following error:

```
root@billy:~/VirtualBox VMs/Helium# VBoxManage startvm Helium --type headless
Waiting for VM "Helium" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR. (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Console, interface IConsole, callee
```

The machine I've moved it to doesn't support VT-x (or it's not enabled in the bios.. but that's because the motherboard battery is dead..replacement on the way - another story entirely). However, I've disabled all the VT-x stuff using VBoxManage and I'm still getting the error.

I've attached my XML config for the server - if anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

XML config: http://pastebin.com/gaHW9fiW

Host Virtualbox is: 4.1.18_Debian

```
Host CPU info: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz 
cpu family   : 6
model        : 23
flags        : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM was registered with 2 CPUs.. this caused the VTx error message. I'm not quite sure why that's something to do with VT-x, I suppose multi-cpu virtualisation probably is a VT-x instruction or something.

So you must make sure your VM only has one cpu if you're getting this error in addition to disabling the other vt-x bits.